# How to get distance in Solr 4 geospatial search?

Tags: search, solr, geospatial, distance

I'm playing with the new Solr 4 geospatial search. Like in an example from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4 I'm trying to get the results like so:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/allopenhours/select?  
&q=foobar  
&fq=geo:%22Intersects(Circle(54.729696,-98.525391%20d=0.08992))%22  
&q={!%20score=distance}  
&fl=*,score
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get distance and score fields in the results set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the  reference [Spatial Search - Returning the distance](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#Returning_the_distance) you can edit your fields parameter to do one of the  following:

- `&fl=*,score,geodist()`
- `&fl=*,score,_dist_:geodist()` - this one will return the distance in the alias `_dist_`

Comment: It returns the following error: `Error parsing fieldname: geodist - not enough parameters:[]`

Comment: Here is a reference for the `geodist()` function http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function

Comment: `A ValueSource isn't directly available from this field. Instead try a query using the distance as the score.`

Comment: The question asks about "Solr 4" specifically, and the answer given links to a document which starts out by saying, "Lucene 4 has a new spatial module that replaces the older one described below... The rest of this document is about the still-supported older approach." So is this really an ideal answer? It seems like it might be based on the older approach which could be going away in Solr4 and beyond.

Comment: @andrexus Your second error probably means you're not passing in a "location" field type to geodist. You might be passing in a Solr 4 location_rpt field, which doesn't appear to work here.

Comment: The *Solr4.0* tag under the Returning the Distance section that I linked to indicates that the item being described is only supported with Solr 4.0 or higher.

Comment: I'm getting the same value _dist_ for every documents ? does there any idea ?

Answer (score 5):

The answer Paige gave is correct. However, the error is shown depending on query given.

`Error parsing fieldname: geodist - not enough parameters:[]`

geodist needs the `sfield` (field which holds the location in the document) and a `pt` (the central point of the circle). If it can't find any of these, it will throw the error shown.

Either add these two to the URL

```
&pt=52.373,4.899&sfield=store&fl=_dist_:geodist()
```

Or add the two (or actually 3: `pt`, `lat` and `lon`) to the `geodist()` function call:

```
&fl:_dist_:geodist(store,52.373,4.899)
```

Note that in the first case, if you have additional geo functions (like `geofilt`) in your query, the `pt` and `sfield` are  used for that as well (unless locally overridden)